# Translate Pinescript function into r code

Tags: python, r, pine-script, tradingview-api

I would like to translate the following function from tradinView into R code f_findDivs:

// Divergences
f_top_fractal(src) => src[4] < src[2] and src[3] < src[2] and src[2] > src[1] and src[2] > src[0]
f_bot_fractal(src) => src[4] > src[2] and src[3] > src[2] and src[2] < src[1] and src[2] < src[0]
f_fractalize(src) => f_top_fractal(src) ? 1 : f_bot_fractal(src) ? -1 : 0

```
    fractalTop = f_fractalize(src) > 0 and (useLimits ? src[2] >= topLimit : true) ? src[2] : na
    fractalBot = f_fractalize(src) < 0 and (useLimits ? src[2] <= botLimit : true) ? src[2] : na
    highPrev = valuewhen(fractalTop, src[2], 0)[2]
    highPrice = valuewhen(fractalTop, high[2], 0)[2]
    lowPrev = valuewhen(fractalBot, src[2], 0)[2]
    lowPrice = valuewhen(fractalBot, low[2], 0)[2]
    bearSignal = fractalTop and high[2] > highPrice and src[2] < highPrev
    bullSignal = fractalBot and low[2] < lowPrice and src[2] > lowPrev
    bearDivHidden = fractalTop and high[2] < highPrice and src[2] > highPrev
    bullDivHidden = fractalBot and low[2] > lowPrice and src[2] < lowPrev
    [fractalTop, fractalBot, lowPrev, bearSignal, bullSignal, bearDivHidden, bullDivHidden]
```

Could you help me please ?
`src = rsi(prices,period = 14)`
high is a serie of highest price for each candle of period
I have trouble to understand the meaning of src[2], high[2]
if src is a serie of data (example 365 days), what mean scr[2] and high[2].

I try this into r code but I'm not so confident :

```
f_top_fractal <- function(src) {
  c(rep(FALSE,4),sapply(0:(length(src)-5), function(i) (src[5+i] < src[3+i]) & (src[4+i] < src[3+i]) & (src[3+i] > src[2+i]) & (src[3+i] > src[1+i])))
  #src[5] < src[3] & src[4] < src[3] & src[3] > src[2] & src[3] > src[1]
}

f_bot_fractal <- function(src) {
  c(rep(FALSE,4),sapply(0:(length(src)-5), function(i) (src[5+i] > src[3+i]) & (src[4+i] > src[3+i]) & (src[3+i] < src[2+i]) & (src[3+i] < src[1+i])))
  #src[5] > src[3] & src[4] > src[3] & src[3] < src[2] & src[3] < src[1]
}

f_findDivs <- function(src, topLimit, botLimit, useLimits) {
  
  fractal_calcul <- f_fractalize(as.vector(src))
  fractalTop <- ifelse(fractal_calcul > 0 & (useLimits & as.vector(src) >= topLimit | !useLimits), as.vector(src), NA)
  fractalBot <- ifelse(fractal_calcul < 0 & (useLimits & as.vector(src) <= botLimit | !useLimits), as.vector(src), NA)
  highPrev <- ifelse(!is.na(fractalTop), as.vector(src), 0) #tail(na.omit(ifelse(fractalTop, src, NA)), 1)   # na(valuewhen(fractalTop, src[2], 0))[2]
  highPrice <- ifelse(!is.na(fractalTop), as.vector(High), 0) #tail(na.omit(ifelse(fractalTop, high[plage], NA)), 1) # na(valuewhen(fractalTop, high[2], 0))[2]
  lowPrev <- ifelse(!is.na(fractalBot), as.vector(src), 0) #tail(na.omit(ifelse(fractalBot, src, NA)), 1)    # na(valuewhen(fractalBot, src[2], 0))[2]
  lowPrice <- ifelse(!is.na(fractalBot), as.vector(Low), 0) #tail(na.omit(ifelse(fractalBot, low, NA)), 1)   # na(valuewhen(fractalBot, low[2], 0))[2]
  bearSignal <- !is.na(fractalTop) & (as.vector(High) > as.vector(highPrice)) & (as.vector(src) < as.vector(highPrev))
  bullSignal <- !is.na(fractalBot) & (as.vector(Low) < as.vector(lowPrice)) & (as.vector(src) > as.vector(lowPrev))
  bearDivHidden <- !is.na(fractalTop) & (as.vector(High) < as.vector(highPrice)) & (as.vector(src) > as.vector(highPrev))
  bullDivHidden <- !is.na(fractalBot) & (as.vector(Low) > as.vector(lowPrice)) & (as.vector(src) < as.vector(lowPrev))
  
  return(list(fractalTop, fractalBot, lowPrev, bearSignal, bullSignal, bearDivHidden, bullDivHidden))
}
```

I have tried to code by myself but the result is not so good